# How to write to error log file in PHP

Tags: php, reference

I want to write a message to an error log file when executing PHP code.

I am trying to use the PHP `error_log()` function [Docs](http://php.net/function.error_log).

But it's not working properly for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working properly"

Comment: Show us [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). Tell use what you get and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Please show your code, tell what you expected to happen, describe what happens instead. Normally the `error_log()` function just works and you have not said what exactly did not work for you so your question is not clear.

Comment: Tutorial on this: http://code2real.blogspot.in/2015/06/php-generate-log-messages-and-save-to.html

Comment: This could stem from a permissions issue where the user you created the error log file for is different than the user being used by Apache to write to the file. Check out '/etc/apache2/envvars/' file for a possible fix.

Answer (score 130):

If you don't want to change anything in your php.ini file, according to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), you can do this.

```
error_log("Error message\n", 3, "/mypath/php.log");
```

The first parameter is the string to be sent to the log.  The second parameter `3` means expect a file destination.  The third parameter is the log file path.

Comment: I'm just doing `error_log("Error message\n")` but nothing appears in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`. :( Any idea why?

Comment: In `php.ini` file check the error_log configuration setting. This setting will hold the file name that errors are written to. e.g. `error_log "log_file_name"`. More details at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: Tutorial on this: http://code2real.blogspot.in/2015/06/php-generate-log-messages-and-save-to.html

Comment: @suspectus, your answer is what I had been looking for long enough. I believe the third parameter could be any file that I like to log the Error message\n to. Am I correct?

Comment: @Pupil, please tell me how long the data stays in the log file written to by error_log()?

Answer (score 59):

you can simply use :

```
error_log("your message");
```

By default, the message will be send to the php system logger.

Comment: If you use this method, be sure that error logging is turned on and that you uncomment the `error_log` directive in php.ini.

Comment: -1 for suggesting, a year after the question was asked, what the OP already said he tried, but did not work for him. Also, there is already a BETTER answer by suspectus, created a year before this answer.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, This is a pretty good alternative too.

Comment: @Pacerier - This answer IS ALREADY WHAT THE OP SAID HE TRIED. So what does it add to the discussion?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve He didn't actually say how he was using it, just that he was trying to use it. The accepted (and very good) answer uses `error_log` too...

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Hi, the goal of my answer was to say that the error_log function send the message by default in your logger (error.log for example). Maybe he made a mistake in using some options of the function. In his question, we don't know how he uses the function. I'm sorry if you think my answer useless.

Answer (score 26):

We all know that PHP save errors in php_errors.log file.

But, that file contains a lot of data.

If we want to log our application data, we need to save it to a custom location.

We can use two parameters in the error_log function to achieve this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

We can do it using:

```
error_log(print_r($v, TRUE), 3, '/var/tmp/errors.log');
```

Where,

`print_r($v, TRUE) :` logs $v (array/string/object) to log file.
`3`: Put log message to custom log file specified in the third parameter.

`'/var/tmp/errors.log'`: Custom log file (This path is for Linux, we can specify other depending upon OS).

OR, you can use `file_put_contents()`

```
file_put_contents('/var/tmp/e.log', print_r($v, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Where:

`'/var/tmp/errors.log':` Custom log file (This path is for Linux, we can specify other depending upon OS).
`print_r($v, TRUE) :` logs $v (array/string/object) to log file.
FILE_APPEND: Constant parameter specifying whether to append to the file if it exists, if file does not exist, new file will be created.

Answer (score 3):

You can use normal file operation to create an error log. 
Just refer this and input this link:
[PHP File Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file.asp)