# Zend : How to log PHP errors

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, error-handling

I have a little problem with Zend, PHP and my Apache server.
So I wandered how to log errors and exception from php into apache logs, in production environment.

Here is my application.ini for prodction Env:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

And, for devlopment Env, I have:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

So what I need is, user doesn't see errors, but they should are logged in my apache log (as in development Env).

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at the access and error logs to see if they're updating?

Comment: Yes, access is updated but not the error one

Comment: You should handle error logging by yourself.

Comment: Check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530039/how-to-write-to-error-log-file-in-php/25606081#25606081

Answer (score 0):

What you want is PHP `error_reporting` turned on (at whatever log level you desire) and `display_errors` off.