# Apache + mod_php how to manually log error?

Tags: php, apache

I have Apache 2.4 and php 5.6 as a module.
Is there any way to send custom error to current 'ErrorLog' file? 
'ErrorLog' directive depends on time (daily logs). 
And I have very specific requirements:

- I cant call `trigger_error` function (error message should not be displayed, only logged);
- I cant use `display_errors` with `none` value
- I cant use @ operator

Any variants?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530039/how-to-write-to-error-log-file-in-php

Comment: I don't know log filename, it's not static. Even more it is different files on local, test and production servers.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to log `error_get_last()` result in some cases. As a worst variant I`ll break my second requirement about display_errors

Answer (score 0):

Any language will let you write to stderr. stderr is redirected to the base servers ErrorLog.  Try fprintf.

Comment: `$err = error_get_last();
$msg = $err['message'];
$stderr = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
fprintf($stderr, "%s", $msg);
fclose($stderr);` Didn't worked