# PHP not writing to error log

Tags: php, error-handling

File structure setup like so,

```
mainDirectory
-app
--logs
---errors.log
-file.php
```

Inside of `file.php` I have,

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "logs/errors.log");
```

I then try to output results like this later,

```
error_log( print_r($response, TRUE) );
```

However it just dumps to console. I then tried various checks like

```
if( file_exists( "logs/errors.log" ) ) {
    echo 'yup';
}
else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

And each time is "nope"

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you.

Comment: does the php service have permission to write to logs directory?

Comment: Hm unsure, do you mean is file writeable?

Comment: take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530039/how-to-write-to-error-log-file-in-php

Comment: if logs cannot be written to then no error log will be created. Use `ls -dl logs` from app directory to check.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 thatryan staff 102 Aug 15 09:02 log/ that is what gets returned

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're running into a permissions problem. I'm running Apache on OSX Sierra and my log files are stored in /var/log. If I try to the line below, I get a `permission denied` error.

```
file_put_contents('/var/log/apache2/errors2.log', 'Hello world');
```

You might consider choosing a location for your error_log that you are certain Apache has permission to write to like `/tmp`.

```
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/errors.log");
```

Try using file_put_contents to test the permissions of the directory before using ini_set which can be a bit terse.